# AsyncLocal test failing when run alongside other tests

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-core, scope

I am trying to create a custom scope class called `AuditScope`, whereby the current scope can be accessed via `AuditScope.Current`.

If there are nested scopes, the current scope is the most nested scope.

I want this to be thread safe, so I am using `AsyncLocal` to ensure the current scope belongs to the current async context and there are no clashes with other requests. This is similar to the `TransactionScope` class if any of you have come across it.

Here is my scope class:

```
public sealed class AuditScope : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<Stack<AuditScope>> ScopeStack = new();

    public int ExecutedByUserId { get; }

    public AuditScope(int executedByUserId)
    {
        ExecutedByUserId = executedByUserId;

        if (ScopeStack.Value == null)
        {
            ScopeStack.Value = new Stack<AuditScope>();
        }

        ScopeStack.Value.Push(this);
    }

    public static AuditScope? Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (ScopeStack.Value == null || ScopeStack.Value.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return ScopeStack.Value.Peek();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ScopeStack.Value?.Pop();
    }
}
```

All my tests are individually passing, however if I run them all at the same  time, one test consistently fails:

```
[Test]
public async Task GivenThreadCreatesScope_AndSecondThreadCreatesScope_WhenCurrentScopeAccessedOnBothThreads_ThenCorrectScopeReturned()
{
    // Arrange
    static async Task createScopeWithLifespan(int lifespanInMilliseconds)
    {
        // This line throws the error, saying it is not null (for the 2000ms scope)
        // No scope has been created yet for this async context, so current should be null
        Assert.IsNull(AuditScope.Current);

        using (var scope = new AuditScope(1))
        {
            // Scope has been created, so current should match
            Assert.AreEqual(scope, AuditScope.Current);

            await Task.Delay(lifespanInMilliseconds);

            // Scope has not been disposed, so current should still match
            Assert.AreEqual(scope, AuditScope.Current);
        }

        // Scope has been disposed, so current should be null
        Assert.IsNull(AuditScope.Current);
    }

    // Act & Assert
    await Task.WhenAll(
        createScopeWithLifespan(1000),
        createScopeWithLifespan(2000));
}
```

Surely since the `using` statements are in different contexts, this should work? Why does pass when run on its own, but not when run alongside the other tests?

For completeness, see below for the other tests I am running it alongside, but I seriously doubt they are directly impacting them:

```
[Test]
public void GivenNoCurrentScope_WhenCurrentScopeAccessed_ThenNull()
{
    // Act
    var result = AuditScope.Current;

    // Arrange
    Assert.Null(result);
}

[Test]
public void GivenScope_WhenScopeDisposed_ThenNull()
{
    // Arrange
    using (var scope = new AuditScope(1))
    {
    }

    // Act
    var result = AuditScope.Current;

    // Arrange
    Assert.Null(result);
}

[Test]
public void GivenScopeCreated_WhenCurrentScopeAccessed_ThenScopeReturned()
{
    // Arrange
    using (var scope = new AuditScope(1))
    {
        // Act
        var result = AuditScope.Current;

        // Arrange
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(scope, result);
    }
}

[Test]
public void GivenNestedScopeCreated_WhenCurrentScopeAccessed_ThenNestedScopeReturned()
{
    // Arrange
    using (var scope = new AuditScope(1))
    {
        using (var nestedScope = new AuditScope(2))
        {
            // Act
            var result = AuditScope.Current;

            // Arrange
            Assert.NotNull(result);
            Assert.AreEqual(nestedScope, result);
        }
    }
}

[Test]
public void GivenNestedScopeCreated_WhenNestedScopeDisposed_ThenCurrentScopeRevertsToParent()
{
    // Arrange
    using (var scope = new AuditScope(1))
    {
        using (var nestedScope = new AuditScope(2))
        {
        }

        // Act
        var result = AuditScope.Current;

        // Arrange
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(scope, result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there must have been a reference issue somewhere, as replacing `Stack<AuditScope>` to `ImmutableStack<AuditScope>` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Like mine, I believe your issue is in your Dispose:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    ScopeStack.Value?.Pop();
}
```

TLDR; is that I'm willing to bet if you change it to this...

```
public void Dispose()
{
    ScopeStack.Value?.Pop();
    if(ScopeStack.Value.Count == 0)
         ScopeStack.Value = null;
}
```

...your code will work as expected, even without the ImmutableStack.

AsyncLocal feels similar to ThreadStatic and when used in an async context (like MVC). It gives the same separation you'd expect per call context, but addresses the problem created by that context being serviced by different threads.

Unlike ThreadStatic though, the AsyncLocal context DOES flow down to child threads in the same call context.

In the case of our unit tests, that initial call context is the test runner and it's probably running those other tests all in the same thread.  By the time it gets to the test in question, your ScopeStack is initialized and then passed down into the child threads.  You could probably reproduce the same error by simply creating and destroying a ScopeStack right before you kick of the tasks.

Setting it to null allows it to be newly initialized inside of the threads instead and AsyncLocal doesn't flow back up (the child threads will all initialize their own since they won't see it established already).

The ImmutableStack fixes it because even though it flows down, you're never actually making a change to the original.  The only problem here is that if you want to do some invalid nesting detection or not allow disposal from a parent prior to the child, you won't be able to see such changes made by child scopes.  Of course that might already be out of reach if you need to start multiple siblings off the same parent (and at that point they can't share a stack).